# Mobile App and website on app engine using same data

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have developed a website in Java/JSF/HTML5 in google app engine. I want to create a mobile app using the same data.

I am trying to create an cloud endpoints web service to provide the data to/from the mobile app. but it creates another version on the default service in the app. 
Maybe I need to create another service in the google app engine application, is there any way to be created?

I couldn't find any examples about this. Could you please point me to some preferably in Java.

Comment: do you want the endpoints served by the same (default) app service or do you want a separate (additional) service for it? You should show your config files.

Comment: I'd prefer to use the same default app but additional service would be also fine.

Comment: You can easily just add new endpoints within the default service.  Just have responses return a JSON object.  Depending on what your responses are currently, you could also create a custom header in the mobile app request, test for it, and tailor the response to mobile.

Comment: Could you please provide some example I have tried adding but to no avail.